# Scraping all possible tags and putting them into one variable using Go Colly

Tags: go, web-scraping, go-colly

I need to scrape different tags from a list of sites, put in variable and then put them in a .csv list. For example, all lines where the author of the article is mentioned (div.author, p.author etc). On all sites, the location of this line and the tags are different, so I need to create a conditional and regular expression to filter that tags.

This is my code, where I find 1 possible author tag and append it to `articleCollection`. I tried if and for conditions, but can't put right variant it into `author_name` variable.

```golang
c.OnHTML("body", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
    author_name := e.DOM.Find("div.author").Text()

    if author_name == "" {
        log.Println("Author not found \n")
    }

    author := Authors{
        Author: author_name,
    }

    articleCollection = append(articleCollection, author)
})
```

Also, I tried implement condition like this for find all

with author class, but it didn't work, because `author_name declared and not used` :

```golang
if author_name == "" {
    author_name := e.DOM.Find("p.author").Text()
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```golang
if author_name == "" {
    author_name = e.DOM.Find("p.author").Text()
}
```

instead of

```golang
if author_name == "" {
    author_name := e.DOM.Find("p.author").Text()
}
```

Using `:=` will allocate a new variable, and in your case, it is `author_name`, a new variable that is only valid within that `if` block. and you are not using it on anything after declaring the variable, that is why the error comes up

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new to Go and make such a simple mistakes. Have a good day.

Comment: @MaximZhukotsky kindly marks the answer as correct by clicking the check mark :-)